# Why does source code in my header of report appear?

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, sourcecode

In my header is source code where nothing is supposed to be.
Main document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter.\quad}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{FirstChapter}
\lipsum[2] %Everything fine here.
\restoregeometry
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark \rightmark}
\chapter*{LastChapter}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And when I include `LastChapter` (and several others, which work fine) only the `LastChapter` makes problems with the header (btw: the footer is empty, that's OK). The last line of the `PreLastChapter` is `\clearpage`. Does that matter?

Has this something ot to with the fact that I changed the geometry several times before?

Note: I would like to not throw something out of this source code, it works fine except that one little error. (I updated all of my packages yesterday, I use TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX).

Comment: If I run your example I get an error `! Package xkeyval Error: \`inputenc' undefined in families `blx@opt@pre'.`  If that occurs in your real document you need to fix that before looking at the output, if not please fix the example to be error free and demonstrate the problem with a header.

Comment: It appears for more than several compilations already but it didn't make some problems so far so I ignored it unless I don't know where it comes from neither to fix it in *which* file (document/line).     So it's about this error? I also ignored it because my TeXnicCenter tells me `\begin{document}` is an illegal parameter / an undefined controol sequence.

Comment: if you get a tex error it really isn't worth even looking at the resulting pdf. When recovering from errors tex tries to get into a state that it can carry on to check more of the document but it does not try to make sensible typeset output. If I scroll past the error then as its a one page document, I just get a chapter head and no page head, what did you expect?

Comment: unless you make an example that demonstrates the problem, no-one will be able to help.  You have neither shown your bad output nor produced code that  puts "source code in the header" (what do you mean by that?)

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/ljj9es

Comment: I added the picture thanks, but can't debug unless you fix the example to show something similar

Comment: "source code in the header": the following text appears in the header where the text of the header line stands. =‘“ "1-1˙ ˙ 30001ex-30001ex- 20001ex- 15001ex-1250 fromoriglanguage
fromoriglanguage --LITERATUR =‘“ "1-1˙ ˙ 30001ex-30001ex- 20001ex- 15001ex-1250
fromoriglanguage fromoriglanguage --LITERATUR

Comment: yes see the image now, but can't guess without  seeing some code that produces that.

Comment: I'm already searching in TheChapterBefore.tex, but I can't find it -.-

Comment: to make an example, just start from a copy of your original and delete everything that you can delete while still showing the problem. Posting code that doesn't demonstrate the problem doesn't allow anyone to help.

Comment: I fixed a few things in your preamble and it runs without error but as it now has no errors and doesn't show the problem you are asking about I can do no more, sorry.

Comment: It also only came in the main document,  but when I compiled with the nearly same preamble in the Chapter-files, that error didn't come... And I think I got the rebelling "package"... At least the one making the error that `\begin{docuzment}`wasn't accepted...

Comment: It mainly was the last two options of `\usepackage{biblatex}`.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Seems nobody gave you a helpful link so far. In order to debug problems like you have, you can use a simple mechanical algorithm: [How to findn the reson of failure](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it seems here are two missunderstandings.  The first one is a missing knowledge about the resulting typing area, the second one is a missunderstanding of command `\titlespacing`.

Let us start with the typing area.  I added option `showframe` to package `geometry` to show the resulting typing area, the area for the header, footer and margins.

The command `\titlespacing` is defined as (see documentation of package `titlesec`, chapter 3.2 Spacing):

```
%\titlespacing*{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt} % <=================== your choice
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt} % <=================== my suggestion  
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt} %   <=================== no negative distance
```

Your choice (`-50pt`) results in the fact that your chapter heading is moved upside into the reserved space for the header.  The reason, that you see this effect not on the first page is that there is no rule in the header. On the second page the chapter header is written above the header rule.

With my choice (`-20pt`) has only the effect that your chapter heading is moved a little bit up, but is not moved into the header (and the header rule for page 2).

With no negative distance (`0pt`) I think one get the best result, but that is off cource my personal opinion ...

Please have now a look to my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[%
  headheight=15pt,
  showframe        % <===================== to visualize the typing area
]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter.\quad}{0pt}{}
%\titlespacing*{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt} % <====================== -50pt
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{FirstChapter}
\lipsum[1-8] %Everything fine here.
\restoregeometry
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark \rightmark}

\chapter*{LastChapter}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: first page of pdf]

and the third page:

[image]

That should be the result you want, I think.

With you choice of `-50pt` you get (I show only the top part of the pages) for page 1:

[image: wrong -50pt first page]

and for the third page (see the marked bottom of the header line with the red arrow):

[image]

Hope this helps you to see your missunderstandings ...

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}` as `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{40pt}` and run the code you will get the desired result.